# Where/how should I store table metadata (table names, primary keys)?

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a database with such a schema:

```
Product
-------
ProductID
Name
Price
Attribute1ID
Attribute2ID
Attribute3ID
Attribute4ID
Attribute5ID
...

Attribute1
----------
Attribute1ID
Attr_name

Attribute2
----------
Attribute2ID
Attr_name

Attribute3
----------
Attribute3ID
Attr_name
```

Now, I'm trying to create a catalog, and would like to be able to filter through the products according to their attributes. e.g.

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Price
FROM Product p
JOIN Attribute1 a1 USING (Attribute1ID)
JOIN Attribute2 a2 USING (Attribute2ID)
WHERE (a1.Attr_name = [some value])
AND (a2.Attr_name = [some value]);
```

I would like to dynmically create (according to, say, GET data) such queries in PHP. My concern is about how/where to store the table names and primary keys, so that my PHP code can assemble the queries.

Would it be appropriate to simply store this information in an array in the PHP file? e.g.

```
$tableAndPK['attr-1'] = array('table'=>'Attribute1','pk'=>'Attribute1ID');
$tableAndPK['attr-2'] = array('table'=>'Attribute2', 'pk'=>'Attribute2ID');
$tableAndPK['attr-3'] = array('table'=>'Attribute3', 'pk'=>'Attribute3ID');
// etc... where 'attr-x' is the corresponding form input name.
```

Or would it be wiser to have this information in another table, that can be retrieved from the database every time the catalog is loaded? e.g.

```
SELECT HtmlName, TableName, PrimaryKey
FROM AttributeMetadata
WHERE HtmlName IN ([form input names that are required]);
```

Or perhaps there's a(n) (obviously better) way to go about this? Some design pattern that I could look into, or pre-existing mechanism in PHP or MySQL that might aid me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might soon hate yourself for using a schema like this. I strongly suggest that you will enormously simplify your task if your schema looks more like this:

```
Product
-------
ProductID
Name
Price

Attributes
----------
AttrID
Attr_name

ProdAttribMap
-------------
ProductID
AttrID
```

Then join `Product` to `Attributes` via `ProdAttribMap`, something like this:

```
select
  *
from
  Product
  left join ProdAttribMap on Product.ProductID = ProdAttribMap.ProductID
  left join Attributes on ProdAttribMap.AttrID = Attributes.AttrID
where
  Attr_name = "blah"
;
```

To perform some operations you can do with just the one simple join like above, and other times you might have to join Attributes multiple times, and apply different `where` clauses, but you now have a situation where you only EVER have 3 tables, so you don't really have any meta data to store.

Also, you can have any number of attributes without changing the schema of your database, so maintenance is easier.

Note that the word attributes is IMO a bit dodgy here, because you're using values without names, and that, I would say means they are really tags, not attributes, but it's a minor terminology complaint.

If you were really doing attributes, to be fully denormalised, you'd change your `Attributes` table like this:

```
Attributes
----------
AttrID
AttrNameID
Attr_value
```

And, add a new table:

```
AttributeNames
--------------
AttrNameID
Attr_name
```

The attribute names table would have `Attr_name` values like 'age' or 'gender', whilst the values like '30' and 'male' would be in the `Attr_value` column of the `Attributes` table.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a bigger application I suggest you use an ORM that handles all these things for you.

There are plenty of ORM's out there like doctrine that will handle all the relation stuff for you.

What you're trying to do by making the pk's configurable is build your own ORM.

Comment: This is a good practice even in small applications.  Reinventing this wheel will be time consuming and error prone.

Comment: NO IT IS NOT. ORM can save initial development costs but it is VERYexpensive to maintain.